# Ошибка прав доступа libmysql.dll в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, visual-studio, dll

[image]

Часть кода, где происходит подключение к базе данных.

```
MYSQL *connection, mysql;
MYSQL_RES* result;
MYSQL_ROW row;
int query_state;
MYSQL* Connection() {
    mysql_init(&mysql);
    connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql, "localhost", "root", "6592", "test1", 3306, 0, 0);
    if (connection == NULL) { cout << mysql_error(&mysql) << endl; }
    return connection;}
```

Вот код запроса:

```
void InTable() {
    string request = "insert into test value(1);";
    query_state = mysql_query(connection, request.c_str());
    result = mysql_store_result(connection);
    mysql_free_result(result);}
```

Вот в этой строке `result = mysql_store_result(connection);`
Выдает ошибку, которая снизу. Как можно исправить?

Comment: *Вот код запроса* Код синтаксически ошибочен. Должно быть value**s**. И таблица test должна иметь строго одно поле, способное принять значение 1.

Comment: *Вот в этой строке `result = mysql_store_result(connection);` Выдает ошибку*. Запрос INSERT не возвращает набор записей. Это так, к слову...

Comment: @Akina исправил запрос, но это не помогло. Мне кажется, что это что-то с visual studio.